# Maven and generating check sums

Tags: maven, jboss, checksum

I'm new to Maven and we want a way to use checksums to determine when files have been changed in SVN for troubleshooting deployment purposes. We have 2 artifacts that are deployed in our respective environments:
(a) 1 WAR file
(b) 1 configuration folder containing a few .properties files and a few XML files.

We want to track if any of the config files have been modified since building the original WAR file since sometimes developers have added configuration entries that are no longer in synch with the WAR file. We think the ability to compare check sums might be a good help in this area. We use Maven as our build tool and JBoss is our app server.

In pom.xml I added a  entry for the maven-install-plugin. When I perform a build using "maven clean package" and then a hard deploy to JBoss by Maven "mvn jboss:hard-deploy" I don't see any specific check sums files.

pom.xml entry for maven-install-plugin contains a  element which contains a  element that contains a text value of true. According to documentation I have widely read this should generate check sum files. I have searched for these check sum files after both the build and deploy to JBoss. I'm new to Maven and checksums and I have searched online for the last few days unsuccessfully so that is the only reason I'm reaching out for help.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help,

-Kevin

Comment: Setup a repository like Nexus and use it to store all release artifacts. All artifacts in a Maven repository will have associated checksums. Use this repository for deployments and you'll have an absolute record at a point in time. This is common practice in Maven. Using a Maven repository has other benefits such as proxying 3rd party repos like Maven Central.